# Pass connection object between modules in

Tags: python

at now i have a unique python script with a class that handles Netmiko SSH connections with some methods such as connect, get some info from device, etc... and works well.

Here are an example of my code:

```py
### main.py

from netmiko import Netmiko

class device:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def connect(self, ip, username, password, port):
    self.device = {"user": "username", "pass"....}
    self.connection = Netmiko(**self.device, global_cmd_verify=false)

  def get_var_log(self):
    output = self.connection.send_command("ls /var/log")
    return output


mydevice = device()
mydevice.connect()
print (mydevice.get_var_log())

mydevice.disconnect()
del mydevice
```

I want to take out '**get_var_log()**' method from this script and put it into another class inside a module named "mymodule" to optimize code:

```py
### mymodule.py

class get:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def get_var_log(self):
    output = self.connection.send_command("ls /var/log")
    return output
```

My intention is to be able to call the method in this way from any part of the code:

```py
mydevice = device()
mydevice.connect()
print (mydevice.get.get_var_log())

mydevice.disconnect()
del mydevice
```

The problem is that i don't know how can i pass the "**self.connection**" object to this new class/module.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The statement `mydevice.get.get_var_log()` is not possible as the .`get` is not part of the `device` class

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make the connection accessible outside of the `device` class.

```
class device:
  def __init__(self):
    self.connection = connect()

  def connect(self, ip, username, password, port):
    self.device = {"user": "username", "pass"....}
    return Netmiko(**self.device, global_cmd_verify=false)
```

Then you need to make the `get` class aware of the connection.

```
class get:
  def __init__(self, connection):
    self.connection = connection
    pass

  def get_var_log(self):
    output = self.connection.send_command("ls /var/log")
    return output
```

Also of note, your `connect()` method accepts args but you don't pass any or use them.

Comment: Thank you for your tip!. I have tested it and works as i want ;-)